# How to save VennDiagram as PNG figure in matplotlib_venn

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, matplotlib-venn

With the following code I tried to create the Venn diagram
then saved as a file.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
set2 = set(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
plt = venn2([set1,set2],('Set1','Set2'))
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

But it gave me error. What's the right way to do it?

This is the example figure where I exceuted under Ipython:
[image]

Comment: This solution wasn't working for me, I'd only get an empty png. Then I found this other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289004/how-to-save-venndiagram-as-png-file-in-matplotlib-venn), which explained what I was getting wrong. So, if anyone here has the same problem as I do, here it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`venn2` is a function that returns an instance of `VennDiagram`.
However, the class `VennDiagram` does not have the method savefig as you wish.
What you are trying to do is to save the resulting figure. For that, based on your loaded modules, you can use the following command.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('test.png')
```

instead of

```
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

This might solve the problem for you.

Cheers

[image]