# How to save VennDiagram as .png file in matplotlib_venn

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I would like to save a venn diagram as a .png (or some other file) to insert into a document.  I am using matplotlib_venn.

Following the solution here:

[How to save VennDiagram as PNG figure in matplotlib_venn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206826/how-to-save-venndiagram-as-png-figure-in-matplotlib-venn)

I just get an empty (white) .png file as follows:

[image]

My code is:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

venn2(subsets=(5,8,4))
plt.savefig(path+'venn1A.png')
```

Comment: write `plt.savefig(path+'venn1A.png')`  before `plt.show()` because `plt.show()` free memory space taken by graph so if you write `plt.savefig(path+'venn1A.png')` after that then you will got an empty(white) image

Comment: If you submit this as an answer I will mark as accepted.  Otherwise, I can do it later.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write `plt.savefig(path+'venn1A.png')` before `plt.show()` because `plt.show()` free memory space taken by graph so if you write `plt.savefig(path+'venn1A.png')` after `plt.show()` then you will got an empty(white) image.

**Note:-if you don't provide the .png extension then by default savefig() method saves images in png format**

**FURTHER NOTE:**
ATOM IDE displays diagrams automatically (ie `plt.show()` is implicit).  It is thus necessary to submit all lines of code together rather than each line individually.